# Getting an error"TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object" after excuting script in ApacheSpark. can anyone please debug my code?

Tags: python, pyspark

Hi I am following frank kane's course on apachespark with python. Here i am trying to calculate total amount spent by different customers.I have mentioned the error below.Kindly help. following is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("MaxTemperatures")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

def parseline(lines):
    fields=lines.split(',')
    customerId=int(fields[0])
    dollars=float(fields[2])
    return (customerId, dollars)

text = sc.textFile("file:///Sparkcourse/SparkCourse/customer-orders.csv")

rdd= text.map(parseline)
reduction= rdd.map(lambda x: x[1]).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
sortedvalues=reduction.sortByKey()
final= sortedvalues.collect()
for i,j in final:
    print(i,j)
```

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want to do and I have the intuition that you have at least one error in your code: you should use `reduceByKey` the following way:

```py
reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

I think in your case, every steps you want to use can be translated in the framework of the `DataFrame API` which will be easier to use. `RDDs` are not the easiest structure to handle when you use simple operations as sums, etc. (and `DataFrames` will be faster)

So I can propose you something like that. You will probably have to change the `schema` statement to match your `csv` structure. Assuming your `spark` session is named `spark`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.types as pst
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

schema = pst.StructType([
    pst.StructField("customerId", pst.IntegerType(), True),
    pst.StructField("dollars", pst.IntegerType(), True),
    pst.StructField("productid", pst.IntegerType(), True)])

(spark.read
   .csv("file:///Sparkcourse/SparkCourse/customer-orders.csv", header = False, schema = schema)
   .groupBy('customerId')
   .agg(psf.sum("dollars").alias("dollars"))
   .sortBy('dollars')
)
```

Comment: i havent reached data frame concept yet. Btw i had tried using the reduceByKey code you have mentioned above.It still shows the same error.

Comment: What do you want to do with `map(lambda x: (x[0]/x[1])`? In my understanding, you divide your key (customerId) by the number or Times it is counted (second dimension of your `reduceByKey`). Not sure this is What you want to do ?

Comment: I think your error comes from the `mapValues` step. Since you alrezdy have a tuple (customerId, dollar) you can directly do the reducebykey. Try to remove mapvalues test and do a `reduction.take(5)` before trying to create `sortedvalues`

Comment: Hi, I have made some changes to the code and I am still getting an error.I have updated the question. I am here trying to get the total amount spent by the unique customer ID's.Please check the above code.